# Binary search or iterator based on a function instead of a collection?

Tags: c++, binary-search, lower-bound

As a simple example, let's say I want to find the square root of N by using binary search. But I don't want to implement the binary search myself, but use `std::lower_bound` or similar. Can I write something like

```
int square(int x) {
  return x * x;
}

int square_root(int N) {
  // Assume I know the results is between 0 and 10000.
  return std::lower_bound(0, 10000, square, N);
}
```

Is there a function like that that instead of taking values from the iterators of a collection takes the values from a callback function?

Or, is there a way to create iterators based on a function rather than a collection so that I can do something like:

```
return std::lower_bound(func_it(0, square), func_it(10000, square), N);
```

I know I can write this function or iterator myself. I'm asking if such functionality exists in the standard library because it seems like it would be useful but I wasn't able to find it.

Comment: There is no such functionality in the standard library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++20's standard library includes ranges, which was basically made for this kind of stuff. You'll want a `transform_view`:

```
int square(int x) { return x * x; }
int sqrt(int x) {
    auto space = std::views::iota(0, x + 1) | std::views::transform(square);
    return std::lower_bound(space.begin(), space.end(), x) - space.begin();
}
int main() {
    std::cout << "sqrt(123): " << sqrt(123) << "\n"; // gives 12: (12-1)^2 < 123 <= 12^2
}
```

This creates the sequence `0, 1, 2, ..., x` (`iota(0, x + 1)`), squares every element (`| transform(square)`) (read that `|` as the "pipe," a la `sh`), searches for the first one greater than or equal to the radicand, and gives its index/original value (by differencing its location with the sequence's `begin`). For nonnegative integral `x`, `0 <= sqrt(x) <= x`, so `iota(0, x + 1)` is a suitable source. Inserting a `std::cerr << x << "\n";` in `square` confirms that `std::lower_bound` does not fall back to linear search.

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:43,endLineNumber:6,positionColumn:43,positionLineNumber:6,selectionStartColumn:43,selectionStartLineNumber:6,startColumn:43,startLineNumber:6),source:'%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Cranges%3E%0A%0Aint+square(int+x)+%7B+return+x+*+x%3B+%7D%0Aint+sqrt(int+x)+%7B%0A++++auto+space+%3D+std::views::iota(0,+x+%2B+1)+%7C+std::views::transform(square)%3B%0A++++return+std::lower_bound(space.begin(),+space.end(),+x)+-+space.begin()%3B%0A%7D%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+%22sqrt(123):+%22+%3C%3C+sqrt(123)+%3C%3C+%22%5Cn%22%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:54.886113152094055,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:executor,i:(argsPanelShown:'1',compilationPanelShown:'0',compiler:g101,compilerOutShown:'0',execArgs:'',execStdin:'',fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B2a+-pedantic',source:1,stdinPanelShown:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+10.1+Executor+(Editor+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),k:45.113886847905945,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)

Comment: I had to `#include <ranges>`, install g++-10 and use -std=c++2a but then it worked. Thanks!